# For loop to get the average values of indices across multiple vectors (Time Series Average Plot)

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently developing my pipeline in R for data processing/analysis.

My data is in a long format (sample rate = 1000Hz). Throughout the dataframe I have added a trialNum variable for each trial, but I am having issues reshaping my data to wide.

What I am trying to do, and I think should be possible with a for loop or two... Is to get the average value of x at index 1:100, based on the trialNum.

Here is a simple version...

| Pupil Size | TrialNum |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 1 |
| 502 | 1 |
| 504 | 1 |
| 506 | 1 |
| 508 | 1 |
| 507 | 2 |
| 508 | 2 |
| 510 | 2 |
| 511 | 2 |
| 512 | 2 |
| 513 | 3 |
| 515 | 3 |
| 514 | 3 |
| 512 | 3 |
| 515 | 3 |

So stated simply... I would get the first index of Pupil size for each TrialNum, and average together, and add to a new variable (average_pupil_size).

In this example, each trial has 5 inputs, so I would end up with a variable output of length = 5...

```
average_size <- c(507, 508, 509, 510, 512)
```

I could then plot this signal for all my trials... I hope I have explained myself clearly... Apologies for the chaos that is my mind.

Does anyone know how to do this? It is a bit beyond me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is 509? And why is 511 not in your average_size?

Comment: There are 5 values of pupil size for each Trial Num (Let's say the value was taken each second for this hypothetical data.

507 is the average pupil size for the first value within each trialNum.

So we have 5 average values.

In my real data I have hundreds of thousands of lines of data, but I will be setting the trialLength to 5 seconds (5,000 samples) - I then plan to use a for loop to get the average value of index 1 across trials (there are hundreds of trials)

Hopefully I am making more sense... Apologies again! Thanks for the input :)

Comment: In the context of your expected output vis-a-vis your sample data, why is 509 in it (when the data doesn't contain 509)? And why is 511 excluded, even though it is part of trial num 2? In SO, we usually don't consider too much about how and why data is collected. More interested in how to reproduce your issue and address with code. So it's a simple question on the disparity between average_size and your data provided.

Comment: So pupil size @ index 1 for trialNum 1 (500), and index 1 (technically this is pupilsize[6]) for trialNum2 (507), and finally index 1 of trialNum3 (pupilsize[11]) =(513). So the average for the first index would be 506.66 (507).

509 is the average of the 3rd index of pupil size, relative to trialNum ((504 + 510 + 514)/3 = 509.33 (509))

Comment: `colMeans(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(unstack(df1), t)), na.rm = TRUE)` if the lengths are different, `rowMeans(unstack(df))` if all are of equal lengths as given in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could add an index within each TrialNum using `row_number()`, and then group-summarize within those.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(TrialNum) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Pupil.Size))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  index   avg
  <int> <dbl>
1     1  507.
2     2  508.
3     3  509.
4     4  510.
5     5  512.
```

Comment: Jon! 

You're amazing! You're all amazing!

Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 1):

in base R, if the data has same length for each trial, eg in this case 5, we can do:

```
rowMeans(unstack(df))

[1] 506.6667 508.3333 509.3333 509.6667 511.6667
```